# Dual Citizen with Name Difference on Passport

Tags: air-travel, passports, dual-nationality

I tried looking for an answer which is specific to situation on the boards but have not been able to find one or they are for different countries and may have a different policy.

I am travelling to the US from the Philippines and hold both a US and PH passport. For the sake of this example my name on my birth certificate is as follows: Jonh Mike Cruz Smith, broken down as

First Name: John Mike // Middle Name: Cruz // Family Name: Smith

My PH Passport lists my name as First Name: John Mike // Middle Name: // Family Name: Smith

My US Passport lists my name as First Name: John Mike // Family Name: Cruz Smith

The US passport combined by middle and last names and the PH passport omitted the whole name altogether. My ticket is issued under my US Passport name since I am travelling to the US.

When I leave Manila, I will need to present my PH passport to prove that I have not overstayed in the Philippines; however, immigration also requires that I am able to prove that I have the ability to legally enter my final destination which is my US Passport, thus having to present both passports.

Will this be a problem for me if I present both passports and my birth certificate?

I am assuming that I need to use the PH Citizen lane at the airport leaving Manila, is this correct?

PS. I am transiting through Singapore, but doubt that presenting just my PH passport will be sufficient since I'm booked on a one-way ticket with no return.

Comment: @jpatokal is this really a dupe though ? this question is about name differences

Comment: @blackbird Case 2 & 4 in the accepted answer discuss precisely this scenario.